# how to split sting that contains string characters and integer?

Tags: php, arrays, string, function

Hi consider this for example

```
  abcd.exe  1234  xyrs  6  987654
  fghij.exe 1235  xyqs  5  897645
```

is the data supplied to a variable, now I want to get "**abcd.exe**" in to separate variable and "**987654**" in to another variable or could be two arrays

Comment: $exploded_string=explode("",$string);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### A regex free solution.

```
<?php
$str='abcd.exe  1234  xyrs  6  987654
fghij.exe 1235  xyqs  5  897645';

foreach(explode(PHP_EOL,$str) as$k=>$v)
{
    $v = explode(' ',$v);
    $arr[]=$v[0];
    $arr[]=$v[count($v)-1];
}

print_r($arr);
```

You can access those variables like `echo $arr[0];` that prints `abcd.exe` .. likewise for your other variables.

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => abcd.exe
    [1] => 987654
    [2] => fghij.exe
    [3] => 897645
)
```

If you want them in a set... use `array_chunk`

```
$arr = array_chunk($arr,2);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => abcd.exe
            [1] => 987654
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => fghij.exe
            [1] => 897645
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this- you can use php explode

```
<?php

$str='abcd.exe 1234 xyrs 6 987654 fghij.exe 1235 xyqs 5 897645';

$arr=explode(' ', $str);
$one=$arr[0];
$two=$arr[4];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use explode method to do this as

```
$vararr=explode(" ","abcd.exe 1234 xyrs 6 987654 fghij.exe 1235 xyqs 5 897645");
```

$exe=$vararr[0];
$numb=$vararr[4];

Answer (score 0):

Use explode() method to split the string into array. After that check each element of array if it is numeric or not. On the basis of it's type, create two arrays. One will contains numeric values and other one string values. Code is given below:

```
$string = "abcd.exe 1234 xyrs 6 987654 fghij.exe 1235 xyqs 5 897645";
$string_array = explode(" ",$string );

$int_arr = array();
$str_arr = array();

foreach($string_array as $val) {
    if (is_numeric($val)) {
        $int_arr[] = $val;
    }
    else {
        $str_arr[] = $val;
    }
}

print_r($int_arr);
print '<br/>';
print_r($str_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can split the string by space (I am assuming that the space an be used as delimiter here, by looking at the string you posted) with the use of in-built split function and create an array of strings.

Then you can loop through each of the element in the array and check if the element is a number or string and based on that you can put them in appropriate bucket or array.

I hope this will help.

Thanks and regards,

Chetan Ranpariya